# Passing Command Line Arguments To HTA Application

Tags: cmd, vbscript, command-line-arguments, hta

I have an HTA application I would like to run from a Command Prompt. 
I've tried everything I could possibly think of and it's just not working!
It just launches the application and that's it.

From Command Prompt I run it with the full path as such:

```
C:\users\xxx\script.hta "arg1" "arg2"
```

which is essentially what I'm trying to accomplish here?

I've gone through numerous pages on here with similar issues but I guess I'm just not putting it together properly!

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:Application
    ID="oHTA"
    APPLICATIONNAME="MSI-BUILD"
    Border = "NO"
    Singleinstance ="YES"
    BorderStyle = "Complex"
    ShowInTaskBar = "YES"
    MaximizeButton = "No"
    MinimizeButton = "No"
    scroll="NO"
    VERSION="2"

 />

<script language = "VBScript">

    Sub RunProgram  

    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Const ForAppending = 8

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


    strCurDir= WshShell.CurrentDirectory

    StrARG = MSINAME.value
    StrARG3 = FPath.value

    strFolder = "D:\SMPSS\PROJECTS\"&MSINAME.value

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
    oFSO.CreateFolder strFolder
    End If


    objShell.Run "D:\SMPSS\MSI-2\1-newproject.vbs " & StrARG , 0, True

    window.close() 

End Sub

Sub Window_onLoad

    Self.Resizeto 890, 300
    document.title = oHTA.applicationName & " v" & oHTA.version

    arrCommands = Split(oHTA.commandLine, chr(34))
    For i = 3 to (Ubound(arrCommands) - 1) Step 2
        Select Case arrCommands(i)
                Case "arg1" 
                    myarg1 = "This is argument 1."
                Case "arg2"
                    myarg2 = "This is argument 2."
        End Select
    Next
    MsgBox myarg1
    MsgBox myarg2

End Sub

</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #b2b2f4">

        <td>MSI-NAME:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="overflow:hidden">
        <td style="resize:none">
        <td style="text-align:right">
        <td style="width: 325px"><input type = "text" name = "MSINAME" id = "MSINAME" size="50" /></td>
        <p>
        <td>PATH:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="overflow:hidden"></td>
        <td style="resize:none"></td>
        <td style="text-align:right"></td>
        <td style="width: 325px"><input type = "text" name = "FPath" id = "FPath" value ="" size="50" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </p>
        <p>
        <input id='submit' type="button" value="Submit" onClick="RunProgram"></td>
        </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-pass-command-line-variables-to-an-hta-when-it-starts/

Comment: That document is what helped me get this far. I just cant figure out why its not working.

Comment: You can start by removing one of the two Window_OnLoad procedures you've got defined. You can't have multiples of the same procedure. I'm wondering how the code you've posted does anything at all. I'm guessing your problem with it not working is that the first OnLoad is the one being executed, and it makes no effort to retrieve the command line arguments.

Comment: @KenWhite I have merged them and updated the code. Its still not grabbing the command line args

Comment: @demo7up, have you used HTA and VBScript before? Have you considered looking to see if all of your opening tags have been closed, _(indenting your code better would certainly help you to spot those)_, and that you haven't closed tags that were never opened in the first place! There are too many issues with the posted code that your question is too broad, I would suggest you run your code through a HTML validator and fix the issues it highlights before requesting help with a specific issue.

Comment: You want to call the HTA with the arguments in double quotes, then split the commandline at double quotes and pick every second element from the resulting array starting at index 3, just like the article Ken linked suggests. Otherwise you'll have a hard time dealing with whitespace.

Comment: My suggestion would be to make a copy of the .hta you have now, remove **all of the code** that does not have to do with fetching the command line arguments passed, and then work with that copy to solve this issue. When you have it working without all of the extra code you have here, you can then start adding code to it. You have too much excess noise in this effort. Solve one problem at a time before you start adding other things.

Comment: I only have one problem, everything else works as it should I just want it to accept command line arguments at this point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the issue was having `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">` in my code once removed everything started working as it should thanks! Also the file wasn't saved as ANSI so it was having invalid character errors. Everything is working great now!